# Kubernetes Provider 2.0.1 "Unauthorized

Tags: authentication, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

```
Unauthorized
```

when i do a plan, my file are remote on bitbucket i think my kubenetes token are expire after 15 min this is my provider setup version 2.0.1

```
provider "kubernetes" { 
  host = data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.endpoint 
  token = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.cluster.token
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.certificate_authority.0.data) 
}
```

When i switch my version for 1.11.1 i receveive this error instead

```
Error: Get http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/aws-auth: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused
```

Please anybody got some advice